# My plot doesn't show line but only dot in graph

Tags: plot, graph, line

I would like to get weather data and visualize it as graph. but my plotting shows only dot. Could you please help me to make it show line for me?

```
import requests
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

city = "osan" #도시
apiKey = "#####################################"
lang = 'en' #언어
units = 'metric' #화씨 온도를 섭씨 온도로 변경
api = f"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q={city}&appid={apiKey}&lang={lang}&units={units}"
result = requests.get(api)
result = json.loads(result.text)

name = result['city']['name']


print('City: ' + name)

for i in range(0, 39):
    
    date = result['list'][i]['dt_txt']
    temp = result['list'][i]['main']['temp']
    print('Time: ' + date)
    print('Temp: ' + str(temp))
    plt.plot(date, temp, 'go-', label='line', linewidth=2)

plt.show()
```